Need to either edit a PDF to replace some text, or create a new PDF page and sandwhich it between two other PDFs, in code
I've written a book that I want to make available for free from a website, but want the second page to show the name and email address of the person that downloaded it, so it is traceable if it gets loose on the net.
The users will be logged into the site, so their name and email address are known.  Then I need an automatic code solution to add their name and email address to the PDF.  I've thought of two options:

OPTION 1: The cleanest way to do this would be to first create the book PDF with a second page with placeholder text like "belongs to John Smith jsmith@somedomain.ext", and then programmatically edit that file to replace the placeholder text with a given user's name and email address.  However, as I've discovered, first by opening the PDF with Notepad++ and then with research, the way text is stored in PDFs is not simple or deterministic.  So this option does not seem workable, unless someone has a trick.

OPTION 2: The other approach might be to save the document title page as a one page PDF, and then pages 3 to the end as another PDF, and then programmatically create a custom second page PDF with the user's name and email address, and then programmatically stick the three PDF's together into one document.


The key is that this must all be doable in code automatically from the website.
Any suggestions for option 1 would be awesome.  Alternatively, for option 2, any suggestions appreciated for software that could help (1) create a custom second page with the user name and email address as described, and (2) stick the title page, second page, and document body together into one PDF?
Thanks very much.

Server side, you could run:
cpdf -create-pdf AND -add-text "foo@bar.com" -o name.pdf
(There are options to change the paper size of the created PDF to match, see the manual).
Then:
cpdf in.pdf 1 name.pdf in.pdf 2-end -o out.pdf
Client side, you could do the same thing with coherentpdf.js. Both solutions are AGPL-licensed.

That is a really nice set of tools.  I will simply add a mostly blank page as the second page of my PDF, and then use cpdf to add the text I want.  I had been searching awhile, great thanks.  For others: https://community.coherentpdf.com/

Hi @johnwhitington - I have been pouring over the cpdf documentation, and cannot see how to -add-text to just page two of my document, which would be the best solution, since then I could preformat page 2 with all the rest of the text, headers and footers etc.  Can cpdf be commanded to add text just to one given page of an existing document?

All commands can operate on any page range. Just put the page range after the file name. e.g cpdf -add-text "foo" in.pdf 2 -o out.pdf.

Many thanks.  That may well be in the user manual somewhere, but I did not find it.  This provides the perfect solution to my problem, simply annotating a second page otherwise completely formatted the way I want, and is much better than I had hoped.  Much appreciated.
